# How does CSRF prevention mechanism validate token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, csrf

I have following `Action methods` in controller named `Default1`.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult testing()
        {

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult testing1()
        {

            return View();
        }
```

Their corresponding `Views` are:

### testing1.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "testing1";
}

<h2>testing1</h2>

<form action="/Default1/testing" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

### testing.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "testing";
}

<h2>testing</h2>

<h1>successfully validated cookie</h1>
```

So first I visit `/Default1/testing1` which sets `HttpOnly` cookie. Response to this request has a hidden field which has a token. Here is that hidden input field.

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="qgahCspc_DQBSQTkFR5_NmPDGygciZPNxt7BmqZE9NpmVzrbbo1N43T3RDjJvrMUmsq4MT5vUqvvQF4SCrSQXnQpKB9THGNA5hVcVu6exIQ1">
```

Following is screen shot of `response header`, Http cookie can be seen in red circle.

[image]

I thought first `HttpOnly` is set and on post request `value from hidden field` & `value of HttpOnly Cookie` are compared if both are equal then we are considered to be validated. But as it can be seen both these values are different. This mechanism is working. Question is how? Is one of these value is encrypted which is decrypted later before comparison.

Comment: Google is your best friend.
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Comment: One of them contains a hash of the current user id too IIRC. It has been answered on here somewhere, but I can't find it (probably the same issue you're having with the search).